# How to encrypt URL information in Django?

Tags: python, html, django

I want to something like

> www.example.com/Link2/add

to be encrypted to

> www.example.com/DMQRzZWMDdGQtbndzBHNsawN0aXRsZQR0ZXN0AzcwMQR3b2UDMjQwMjEwNQ

I tried using django-urlcrypt by follwing these instructions: https://pypi.org/project/django-urlcrypt/ .
But it's not working as it seems to be for an older version of Django( for example, there is no Authentication_Backends in settings.py which is mentioned in the above link)

Is there any other way to encrypt the URLs? Also how would it be decrypted?

Comment: How do you expect the URL to be decrypted to access it?

Comment: What's your specific use case? Without more context we probably won't be able to provide helpful feedback.

Comment: @Chris I have certain pages/functions for which a user has to be logged in in order to access them. I dont want someone to access those directly by altering the URL which is why I want to encrypt it.

Comment: Classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627). The solution is to make sure the user is logged in, not to obfuscate the URL. An obfuscated URL that somebody shares will let the recipient access the page. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests and specifically https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator

Comment: @Chris Actually I have two type of logins: Student Login and Teacher Login. But if the student is logged in then according to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests I'll use login(request, user) to log him in. But he can still access Teacher content using URL as he is logged in.

Comment: @Sunvir, the answer's the same. This is still an authentication issue. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test or https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator, both from the same page I first linked you to

Comment: I should say _authorization_, not authentication.